# ServiceProvider doesn't resolve dependency, returning null

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, mediator

I cannot figure out why the ServiceProvider doesn't get an instance of the registered service

I have the following DI Configuration

```
_serviceCollection.AddScoped<INotificationMediator, NotificationMediator>();
_serviceCollection.AddScoped<INotificationFactory, NotificationFactory>();
_serviceCollection.AddTransient<INotificationHandler<OrderCreatedEvent>, OrderCreatedEventHandler>();
```

This should get the right service : but instead returns null

```
public class NotificationFactory : INotificationFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public NotificationFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public INotificationHandler<TNotification> GetHandler<TNotification>()
        where TNotification : INotification
    {
        var handler1 = _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(INotificationHandler<TNotification>));
        var handler2 = _serviceProvider.GetService<INotificationHandler<TNotification>>(); 

        return handler2;
    }
}
```

Following is the service which I'm trying to resolve

```
public class OrderCreatedEventHandler : INotificationHandler<OrderCreatedEvent>
{
    public Task HandleAsync(OrderCreatedEvent domainEvent, CancellationToken? cancellationToken = null)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And this is the notification

```
public class OrderCreatedEvent : INotification { }
```

I've followed Jbogard MediatR, this is the link https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR

What am i doing wrong here, what might the problem be ?

Btw I've done the same for UseCases Handleing and I have no problem getting the right usecase. Instead of INotification there is IRequest and the logic is the same for all other parts

The way I'm trying to call the NotificationFactor GetHandler is using NotificationMediator

```
public class NotificationMediator : INotificationMediator
{
    private readonly INotificationFactory _notificationFactory;

    public NotificationMediator(INotificationFactory notificationFactory)
    {
        _notificationFactory = notificationFactory;
    }

    public Task DispatchAsync<TNotification>(TNotification notification, CancellationToken? cancellationToken = null)
        where TNotification : INotification
    {
        INotificationHandler<TNotification> notificationHandler = _notificationFactory.GetHandler<TNotification>();

        return notificationHandler.HandleAsync(notification, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And this is called like this

```
aggregate.Events.ForEach(domainEvent => _eventHandler.DispatchAsync(domainEvent));
```

And the aggregate.Events is a list of INotifications

```
public virtual List<INotification> Events { get => _events; }
```

Comment: I think this boils down to the fact that you're eventually requesting an instance of `INotificationHandler<INotification>` rather than an instance of the specific `INotificationHandler<OrderCreatedEvent>` in this case. There's a fair amount of indirection and generics here so I'm not 100% certain on that without trying it myself. At the call to `DispatchAsync`, `domainEvent` is typed as `INotification` and I remember something about generics not being polymorphic like that...

Comment: you are right I've replaced OrderCreatedEvent with INotification and It did in fact got me an Instance. But how can I do it the other way around I mean pass an INotification type not the INotification itself ? thanks

Comment: @MCR, there are at least two possible options. Firstly, you can resolve Handlers not by INotification type, but by some related enum.
Your *INotification* can looks like **interface INotification{  NotificationType Type{get;}  }** where **enum NotificationType { OrderCreated, OrderRemoved }**. And then resolve a handler: *_notificationFactory.GetHandler( notification.Type )*.

Comment: The second option is to use Visitor pattern.

Comment: The code should contain the following interfaces: **interface INotification{ void HandleBy( IHandler handler ); }**,  and   **interface IHandler {  void Process<T>(T item) where T: INotification;  }**.  Then you can create specific notification: **public class OrderCreatedEvent : INotification { public void HandleBy(IHandler handler) {  handler.Process(this); } }**